# How to redirect httaccess

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I tried to redirect but not working even I put the correct code from take it from web.

```
Redirect /index.php?page=8 /?page=8
```

Comment: what is your apache version ?

Comment: Please do mention which URL you are hitting in browser and by which URL in backend you want it served by?

Comment: example.com/    both URL are same domain

Comment: You need to describe the problem in natural language. It looks like you are trying to remove the `index.php` from the visible URL? What is the significance of the query string? Is the query string variable? Or is it fixed as `page=8`? "even I put the correct code" - the code you posted is obviously not "correct" as the `Redirect` directive does not match the query string.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Redirect /index.php?page=8 /?page=8
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive does not match against the query string, so the above directive will never match, so does nothing.

To remove the `index.php` (directory index) from the visible URL, you would need to use mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect a URL of the form `/index.php?page=8` to `/?page=8`. Any query string present on the initial request is simply passed through to the target/substitution unaltered.

The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var ensures we don't get a redirect loop caused by mod_dir (or the Laravel front-controller) rewriting the request to `index.php`.

Clear your browser cache and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect.

---

However, if you did only want to redirect the specific URL `/index.php?page=8` (as stated in the question) to `/?page=8` then you should write the rule like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/index\.php?page=8\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess code should be.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=$1 /?page=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: because it's in laravel

Comment: this code is not working because it's in laravel and most of it url are contain index.php in url